# Yii find condition >=

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I need to find row where summ>=250

I am doing following:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;  
$criteria->condition ='summ >= 250';
$winnerBid = Bids::model()->find($criteria);
```

But I am getting no results.
How to implement?

Comment: How do you print the $winnerBid array?

Comment: Do you have a "summ" column in the table? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: try to make the query work first in your database, does it? then translate it to yii. if you don't have a summ column, then you will have to look into the sum() function and the 'group by' and 'having' clauses

Answer (score 6):

I dont have Yii at hand.
Have you tried this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;  
$criteria->addCondition('summ >= 250');
$winnerBid = Bids::model()->find($criteria);
```

This should work, if `summ` is a column mapped correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It will be usefull, try this -

```
$winnerBid = Bids::model()->find(array('condition'=>"summ >= 250"));
```

Comment: Please, explai better your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$winnerBid = Bids::model()->find('summ >= 250');
if ($winnerBid===null) {
    throw new CHttpException(400,'There is no record in your database with summ>=250.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;  
$criteria->condition ='summ >= 250';
$winnerBid = Bids::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Since you're using `>=` you should use `FindAll()`
This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This might also help: http://yiitutorials.net/easy/yii-getting-info-from-the-database